Will my system be any faster or slower with this LVM mirroring scheme?
I usually boot my system from a single 250G M.2 NVMe SSD (PCIe 3.0 x4). I also have a 240G SATA SSD and a 640G SATA 7200rpm HDD that I currently use for ad hoc backup. The latter will be replaced with proper remote backup, so I have these drives free.
I am considering creating a 240G logical volume using LVM in a RAID1 configuration so that I have two mirrors (i.e. three total images) of my system.
I want to know if this will be slower or faster than my current set up. My primary purpose for this is redundancy but I'd prefer not to degrade performance. I could consider leaving the HDD out of the mix if it's likely to be an issue.
I don't know anything specific about the caching/buffering of the drives off the top of my head. I have 16GB of RAM though and, if it matters, I will be using ext4 for now.

In a mirroring scheme, the slowest-writing storage defines the write speed. So, yes, this will slow your fast SSDs down to the speed of your slower SSD and most importantly to the speed of your HDD.
Read-wise, you'd see the same, unless you tune your RAID setup to prefer reading from the fast storage and abhor reading from slow-seeking storage (if you're planning to do your RAID through LVM, man lvmraid, look for "RAID1 tuning").
All in all, a mirroring setup on block-device level with devices of massively different characteristics like yours seems the wrong choice. Seeing that I've not seen a SATA HDD < 900 GB being produced since circa 2010, it would seem to me that this is likely to be the first device to die in your mirroring setup, anyways, and the one that slows everything down. So, no reliability benefit (quite the contrary – in RAID1 you don't notice when you read incorrect data, so having one of three copies having much higher chance of being incorrect makes your data less safe to be correct!), and performance and electricity cost downsides – I'd simply not include my ancient HDD in this at all.
I think the key word here is this:

that I currently use for ad hoc backup.

So, instead, come up with a less ad-hoc backup strategy. A modern nvme SSD failing completely spontaneously with no warnings is not that common; electrical faults, fire or water damage, or theft, are in a non-datacenter environment probably more common (I sadly have no data on this).
So, I'd say, at 0 hardware investment, I'd set up a regular backup from your main nvme SSD to your SATA SSD and a monthly (or such) backup to the HDD that you store elsewhere.
Investing <50€, though: consumer-brand 250 GB nvme PCIe 3.0 x4 currently cost 18 € in Germany. I don't know the pricing where you are, but frankly, if I was thinking about mirroring, I'd invest in identical-specs hardware attached via PCIe. If this is a desktop or server system, there's (signal-wise passive) PCIe cards that allow you to plug in an nvme M.2 SSD in an existing PCIe slot if your mainboard doesn't have two M.2 slots. Make sure you get your four PCIe 3.0 (or better) lanes.
Note that I'm not certain you gain that much on modern SSDs by buying two SSDs, mirroring your data, vs. buying one, twice as large SSD, not mirroring data: the primary aging and failure mode on SSDs is write exhaustion, so having twice as much storage to wear-level your writes over might actually lead to more reliable storage than mirroring.
Personally: I'd avoid a 14 year old small hard drive for any kind of data I care about. For off-site backup, new, 4 TB, external, modern HDDs are cheap enough.

Thank you for the input. I think you meant "write" in your first paragraph. Yes, I planed to do proper off-site backup in addition to adding some redundancy locally, using borg to a VPS. I edited that into the post now.

thanks, you're right, I meant write. Yeah, well if you do an off-site backup anyways, I'd say you should just toss your HDD, and do regular backups locally from your nvme to your SATA SSD; doesn't sound like you'd really win anything from mirroring.

I think you're right about mirroring SSDs. It would be just as many writes.

Can you elaborate on what you mean about not noticing the data being incorrect in RAID1? I've seen people mention this before but why is that and what do people do about it?

well, imagine this: when putting away a piece of paper into a filing cabinet, you make a photocopy and put that in a separate folder. That's your mirroring. Then, an angry ghost comes around and changes 1 in every 1000 pages at random, both in the "originals" folder and in the "copies" folder, and you don't know which. When you then need a page, you just pick one of the two folders at random, and read the page from it. Well, you now still have a 1/1000 chance of getting a ghost-corrupted page. Your mirroring doesn't help against that at all! What you'd need is an oracle that tells you…

… whether your page is intact or not. Even getting both copies of the same page out of your folders and comparing them doesn't really help. Yeah, you'll know that one of them must be wrong, but you don't know which. You can have three versions, then you can do a majority decision on what is wrong and what is right, but then, you would always need, for every page you read, to wait for the slowest folder to find your page and read it, and that will be terrible in performance.

So, what you need in the case where you want to protect against something else than a storage device failing completely (which means there's now only one copy left to read, and we must assume that it's correct) is at least checksumming of sorts. Data checksumming is not a feature of ext4, but of other file systems like ZFS. Using ZFS with Zmirroring and data checksumming makes more sense than Raid1 + checksumming on top, because the raid layer just gives you the incorrect data, the filesystem would then be signalling a read error, and you couldn't solve that automatically.

ZFS on the other hand integrates the mirroring functionality in the file system and would be like "huh, the copy I read has integrity issues, better read the other copy", and would continue to function. Again, though, in your private use case, it's not obvious that mirroring has a net benefit over having more unused storage on a larger SSD; in our ghost fable up there, the 1/1000 "angriness level" of the ghost gets larger the more often you overwrite data, and your SSD needs to overwrite less often the more unused blocks it has to do wear leveling. I'd say you're probably best off getting a

"prosumer" (say, Samsung Evo current generation) SSD that's larger than you currently need, and not do any mirroring, but be stringent about your backups.

Ah, okay, that makes sense. This is something btrfs and RAID (e.g. level 5) with parity also do, right? I think I see the whole picture now.

yes, btrfs should do that as well. But be careful about non-RAID0 and non-RAID1 btrfs; some of these modes (I forget which) are still marked as "experimental and will lose your data" in the source code (but not necessarily visibly to the user… uhhh)
